# How to fit this table in a page?

Tags: tables

I'm working on a manual that should be finished this week, so I'm in a hurry, sorry if this silly question was done before.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Temario de actividades (Versión A)}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{p{.2\linewidth}}}
\toprule
HORARIO & TEMA & NOMBRE DEL EJERCICIO & OBJETIVO & MATERIAL\\
\midrule
Día 1 & \textbf{Presentación} & ``La telaraña'' & Integración grupal a través de los recursos personales & Una bola de estambre\\
      & Lluvia de ideas & ``Brincón'' & Establecer acuerdos de convivencia grupales & Pelota de esponja.\\
      & Cuestionarios& ``Paseo por el bosque''& Reconocimiento personal y grupal de habilidades, recursos, gustos, objetivos& Anexo: cuestionario emocional,dibujo de árbol y balanza.\\
      & Retroalimentación & ``Esto es un abrazo''& cierre y despedida& abrazos.\\
\midrule
Día 2 & Respiración& ``Música y emociones'' & Se recuerdan acuerdos y recursos & Los acuerdos y recursos de la sesión anterior,música.\\
      & Emociones y tipos de comportamiento& ``la emoción derivada como protagonista'' & Que cada participante reconozca sus emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su comportamiento ante sensaciones desagradables y agradables. & hojas blancas, lápices y colores, información de emociones.\\
      & Autoconcepto & ``Dibujo de sí mismo y para los otros'' & reafirmar el conocimiento de uno mismo a través de la relación que establecemos con los otros. & hojas y colores.\\
      & ``Retroalimentación''& devolución de comentarios respecto a las actividades & \\
\midrule
Día 3 & Inicio de sesión & ``Recapitulación''& retomar algunas reflexiones de las sesiones anteriores& Diapositivas\\
      & Respiración y cuento & ``lectura'' & Autoestima, confianza en uno mismo y las relaciones interpersonales.& Extracto del cuento, e.j. el principito.\\
      & Autoestima y relaciones interpersonales & ``Percepción social y formas de vida'' & Reflexionar sobre la forma de vida actual y su relación con el estrés. Identificar el tipo de situaciones estresantes ante las que se encuentran en este momento de la vida. Dar a conocer los tipos de estresores y comportamientos  al afrontarlos. & Anexo de tipos de comportamiento y estrés.\\
      & Collage & elaborar un collage en el que se represente la forma en la que es percibida la sociedad que nos rodea, valores actuales, creencias, estereotipos, etc. & papel bond, plumones, pegamento, tijeras,revistas, crayones. Preguntas de reflexión\\
      & Retroalimentación y cierre & los collage elaborados por grupos se exponen y retroalimentan & collages.\\
\midrule
Día 4 & comunicación asertiva& ``Teléfono descompuesto''& Que cada participante identifique las características y técnicas en la comunicación asertiva& Diapositivas, plumones.\\
      & Solución de conflictos y trabajo colaborativo& ``el nudo humano'' & reafirmar la importancia del trabajo colaborativo a través de la comunicación no-verbal & dinámica grupal.\\
      & Respiración y reflexión ``Tensión y relajación'' & Distensión e incorporación del grupo a la introspección y reflexión de sus objetivos y proyecto de vida & Música e instrucciones de la actividad.\\
      & Proyecto de vida & ``Proyecto de vida''& reflexionar sobre el proyecto de vida, logros, oportunidades, objetivos, a través de una redacción y compartir algunos escritos al grupo & dibujo del árbol para proyecto de vida.\\
      & cierre del taller &  retroalimentación y despedida & comentarios y reflexiones finales.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you could see the table is broken at the end. Also in the lines 29, 34 and 40 the text of the column 2 clashes with the text of the three, how avoid this? Should I reduce the letter size? I'm not sure since it could be very small for read, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: `Re"-tro"-a"-li"-men"-ta"-ción` and `\begin{tabular}{p{.15\linewidth}p{.21\linewidth}p{.21\linewidth}p{.21\linewidth}p{.21\linewidth}}` should help you for starting. Please ask specific question on singular problems which show some research effort. This is just a "please review code for me for free"-question. You may edit your question to reduce the work for us. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, this table is longer than one page so you should use the `longtable` environment from the `longtable` package.  Setting the typesize to `\small` will help.  Also making columns `\raggedright` will help the spacing of paragraphs.  In addition you need to enable hyphenation of the first word of the paragraphs, which by default TeX will not allow; adding `\hspace{0pt}` before those first words will effect this, but in your case you may as well add it to the column template.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

{\small\begin{longtable}{*{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{.18\linewidth}}}
\caption{Temario de actividades (Versión A)}\\
\toprule
HORARIO & TEMA & NOMBRE DEL EJERCICIO & OBJETIVO & MATERIAL \\
\midrule
\endhead
Día 1 & \textbf{Presentación} & ``La telaraña'' & Integración grupal a través de los recursos personales & Una bola de estambre\\
      & Lluvia de ideas & ``Brincón'' & Establecer acuerdos de convivencia grupales & Pelota de esponja.\\
      & Cuestionarios& ``Paseo por el bosque''& Reconocimiento personal y grupal de habilidades, recursos, gustos, objetivos& Anexo: cuestionario emocional,dibujo de árbol y balanza.\\
      & Retroalimentación & ``Esto es un abrazo''& cierre y despedida& abrazos.\\
\midrule
Día 2 & Respiración& ``Música y emociones'' & Se recuerdan acuerdos y recursos & Los acuerdos y recursos de la sesión anterior,música.\\
      & Emociones y tipos de comportamiento& ``la emoción derivada como protagonista'' & Que cada participante reconozca sus emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su comportamiento ante sensaciones desagradables y agradables. & hojas blancas, lápices y colores, información de emociones.\\
      & Autoconcepto & ``Dibujo de sí mismo y para los otros'' & reafirmar el conocimiento de uno mismo a través de la relación que establecemos con los otros. & hojas y colores.\\
      & ``Retroalimentación''& devolución de comentarios respecto a las actividades & \\
\midrule
Día 3 & Inicio de sesión & ``Recapitulación''& retomar algunas reflexiones de las sesiones anteriores& Diapositivas\\
      & Respiración y cuento & ``lectura'' & Autoestima, confianza en uno mismo y las relaciones interpersonales.& Extracto del cuento, e.j. el principito.\\
      & Autoestima y relaciones interpersonales & ``Percepción social y formas de vida'' & Reflexionar sobre la forma de vida actual y su relación con el estrés. Identificar el tipo de situaciones estresantes ante las que se encuentran en este momento de la vida. Dar a conocer los tipos de estresores y comportamientos  al afrontarlos. & Anexo de tipos de comportamiento y estrés.\\
      & Collage & elaborar un collage en el que se represente la forma en la que es percibida la sociedad que nos rodea, valores actuales, creencias, estereotipos, etc. & papel bond, plumones, pegamento, tijeras,revistas, crayones. Preguntas de reflexión\\
      & Retroalimentación y cierre & los collage elaborados por grupos se exponen y retroalimentan & collages.\\
\midrule
Día 4 & comunicación asertiva& ``Teléfono descompuesto''& Que cada participante identifique las características y técnicas en la comunicación asertiva& Diapositivas, plumones.\\
      & Solución de conflictos y trabajo colaborativo& ``el nudo humano'' & reafirmar la importancia del trabajo colaborativo a través de la comunicación no-verbal & dinámica grupal.\\
      & Respiración y reflexión ``Tensión y relajación'' & Distensión e incorporación del grupo a la introspección y reflexión de sus objetivos y proyecto de vida & Música e instrucciones de la actividad.\\
      & Proyecto de vida & ``Proyecto de vida''& reflexionar sobre el proyecto de vida, logros, oportunidades, objetivos, a través de una redacción y compartir algunos escritos al grupo & dibujo del árbol para proyecto de vida.\\
      & cierre del taller &  retroalimentación y despedida & comentarios y reflexiones finales.\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `tabularx` and package `ltablex` which allows pagebreaks:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex,array,ragged2e}
\let\FNS\footnotesize

\begin{document}
{\tabcolsep=2pt\small\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
  l 
  >{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}p{0.15\linewidth}% \hspace to allow hyphenation of first word
  *2{>{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}X}
  >{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}p{0.15\linewidth}
  @{}}
\caption{Temario de actividades (Versión A)}\\
\toprule
\FNS HORARIO & \FNS TEMA & \FNS NOMBRE DEL EJERCICIO & \FNS OBJETIVO & \FNS MATERIAL\\
\midrule
Día 1 & \textbf{Presentación} & ``La telaraña'' & Integración grupal a través de los recursos personales & Una bola de estambre\\
      & Lluvia de ideas & ``Brincón'' & Establecer acuerdos de convivencia grupales & Pelota de esponja.\\
      & Cuestionarios& ``Paseo por el bosque''& Reconocimiento personal y grupal de habilidades, recursos, gustos, objetivos& Anexo: cuestionario emocional,dibujo de árbol y balanza.\\
      & Retroalimentación & ``Esto es un abrazo''& cierre y despedida& abrazos.\\
\midrule
Día 2 & Respiración& ``Música y emociones'' & Se recuerdan acuerdos y recursos & Los acuerdos y recursos de la sesión anterior,música.\\
      & Emociones y tipos de comportamiento& ``la emoción derivada como protagonista'' & Que cada participante reconozca sus emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su comportamiento ante sensaciones desagradables y agradables. & hojas blancas, lápices y colores, información de emociones.\\
      & Autoconcepto & ``Dibujo de sí mismo y para los otros'' & reafirmar el conocimiento de uno mismo a través de la relación que establecemos con los otros. & hojas y colores.\\
      & ``Retroalimentación''& devolución de comentarios respecto a las actividades & \\
\midrule
Día 3 & Inicio de sesión & ``Recapitulación''& retomar algunas reflexiones de las sesiones anteriores& Diapositivas\\
      & Respiración y cuento & ``lectura'' & Autoestima, confianza en uno mismo y las relaciones interpersonales.& Extracto del cuento, e.j. el principito.\\
      & Autoestima y relaciones interpersonales & ``Percepción social y formas de vida'' & Reflexionar sobre la forma de vida actual y su relación con el estrés. Identificar el tipo de situaciones estresantes ante las que se encuentran en este momento de la vida. Dar a conocer los tipos de estresores y comportamientos  al afrontarlos. & Anexo de tipos de comportamiento y estrés.\\
      & Collage & elaborar un collage en el que se represente la forma en la que es percibida la sociedad que nos rodea, valores actuales, creencias, estereotipos, etc. & papel bond, plumones, pegamento, tijeras,revistas, crayones. Preguntas de reflexión\\
      & Retroalimentación y cierre & los collage elaborados por grupos se exponen y retroalimentan & collages.\\
\midrule
Día 4 & comunicación asertiva& ``Teléfono descompuesto''& Que cada participante identifique las características y técnicas en la comunicación asertiva& Diapositivas, plumones.\\
      & Solución de conflictos y trabajo colaborativo& ``el nudo humano'' & reafirmar la importancia del trabajo colaborativo a través de la comunicación no-verbal & dinámica grupal.\\
      & Respiración y reflexión ``Tensión y relajación'' & Distensión e incorporación del grupo a la introspección y reflexión de sus objetivos y proyecto de vida & Música e instrucciones de la actividad.\\
      & Proyecto de vida & ``Proyecto de vida''& reflexionar sobre el proyecto de vida, logros, oportunidades, objetivos, a través de una redacción y compartir algunos escritos al grupo & dibujo del árbol para proyecto de vida.\\
      & cierre del taller &  retroalimentación y despedida & comentarios y reflexiones finales.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I saw there are four days. Why note break the table manually?

Comment: Why should I do it manually when it can be done automatically??

Comment: To make sure the line containing `Día 3` is the first line of the second page. So that I do not need to flip forward and backward if today is the third day. (This may make no sense. I know nothing about Spanish.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *very* tight layout achieved by

- using `\scriptsize` text,
- reducing the line spacing (`\setstretch`),
- reducing the space between columns (`\tabcolsep`),
- removing space from the left and right edges of the table (`@{}`),
- using uneven column widths,
- shortening the title "Nombre del Ejercicio" to "Ejercicio",
- rotating the day column and removing its title, and
- using the `\raggedright` and hyphenation tricks from Andrew Swann's answer.

The entire table fits on one page (A4 or letter paper). Using such a tight layout may not be advisable.

[image: Output of the example code]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1\textwidth}}
\begin{document}
{\scriptsize
\setstretch{0.76}
\renewcommand*{\tabcolsep}{3.2pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}cx{.118}x{.246}x{.342}x{.207}@{}}
\caption{Temario de actividades (Versión A)}\\
\toprule
&\textsc{Tema} & \textsc{Ejercicio} & \textsc{Objetivo} & \textsc{Material}\\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Día 1}}%
&\textbf{Presentación} & ``La telaraña'' & Integración grupal a través de los recursos personales & Una bola de estambre\\
&Lluvia de ideas & ``Brincón'' & Establecer acuerdos de convivencia grupales & Pelota de esponja.\\
&Cuestionarios& ``Paseo por el bosque''& Reconocimiento personal y grupal de habilidades, recursos, gustos, objetivos& Anexo: cuestionario emocional,dibujo de árbol y balanza.\\
&Retroalimentación & ``Esto es un abrazo''& cierre y despedida& abrazos.\\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Día 2}}%
&Respiración& ``Música y emociones'' & Se recuerdan acuerdos y recursos & Los acuerdos y recursos de la sesión anterior,música.\\
&Emociones y tipos de comportamiento& ``la emoción derivada como protagonista'' & Que cada participante reconozca sus emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su comportamiento ante sensaciones desagradables y agradables. & hojas blancas, lápices y colores, información de emociones.\\
&Autoconcepto & ``Dibujo de sí mismo y para los otros'' & reafirmar el conocimiento de uno mismo a través de la relación que establecemos con los otros. & hojas y colores.\\
&``Retroalimentación''& devolución de comentarios respecto a las actividades & \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Día 3}}%
&Inicio de sesión & ``Recapitulación''& retomar algunas reflexiones de las sesiones anteriores& Diapositivas\\
&Respiración y cuento & ``lectura'' & Autoestima, confianza en uno mismo y las relaciones interpersonales.& Extracto del cuento, e.j. el principito.\\
&Autoestima y relaciones interpersonales & ``Percepción social y formas de vida'' & Reflexionar sobre la forma de vida actual y su relación con el estrés. Identificar el tipo de situaciones estresantes ante las que se encuentran en este momento de la vida. Dar a conocer los tipos de estresores y comportamientos  al afrontarlos. & Anexo de tipos de comportamiento y estrés.\\
& Collage & elaborar un collage en el que se represente la forma en la que es percibida la sociedad que nos rodea, valores actuales, creencias, estereotipos, etc. & papel bond, plumones, pegamento, tijeras,revistas, crayones. Preguntas de reflexión\\
&Retroalimentación y cierre & los collage elaborados por grupos se exponen y retroalimentan & collages.\\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Día 4}}%
&comunicación asertiva& ``Teléfono descompuesto''& Que cada participante identifique las características y técnicas en la comunicación asertiva& Diapositivas, plumones.\\
&Solución de conflictos y trabajo colaborativo& ``el nudo humano'' & reafirmar la importancia del trabajo colaborativo a través de la comunicación no-verbal & dinámica grupal.\\
&Respiración y reflexión ``Tensión y relajación'' & Distensión e incorporación del grupo a la introspección y reflexión de sus objetivos y proyecto de vida & Música e instrucciones de la actividad.\\
&Proyecto de vida & ``Proyecto de vida''& reflexionar sobre el proyecto de vida, logros, oportunidades, objetivos, a través de una redacción y compartir algunos escritos al grupo & dibujo del árbol para proyecto de vida.\\
&cierre del taller &  retroalimentación y despedida & comentarios y reflexiones finales.\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helping. Finally I could make the table works with the package `longtable` as you can see here:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Tabla larga}

\section[Temario de actividades (Versión A)]{Temario de actividades (Versión A)}

    \begin{longtable}{*{5}{p{.20\linewidth}}}
    \caption{Temario de actividades (Versión A)} \\
    \toprule
    \textsc{Horario} & \textsc{Tema} & \textsc{Nombre del Ejercicio} & \textsc{Objetivo} & \textsc{Material}\\
    \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    \toprule
    \textsc{Horario} & \textsc{Tema} & \textsc{Nombre del Ejercicio} & \textsc{Objetivo} & \textsc{Material}\\
    \toprule
    \endhead
    \hline
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{Continúa}\\
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
    Día 1 & \textbf{Presentación} & \emph{La telaraña} & Integración grupal a través de los recursos personales & Una bola de estambre\\
          & Lluvia de ideas & \emph{Brincón} & Establecer acuerdos de convivencia grupales & Pelota de esponja.\\
          & Cuestionarios& \emph{Paseo por el bosque} & Reconocimiento personal y grupal de habilidades, recursos, gustos, objetivos & Anexo: cuestionario emocional,dibujo de árbol y balanza.\\
          & Retroalimentación & \emph{Esto es un abrazo} & cierre y despedida& abrazos.\\
    \midrule
    Día 2 & Respiración & \emph{Música y emociones} & Se recuerdan acuerdos y recursos & Los acuerdos y recursos de la sesión anterior,música.\\
          & Emociones y tipos de comportamiento & \emph{la emoción derivada como protagonista} & Que cada participante reconozca sus emociones con el objetivo de mejorar su comunicación y su comportamiento ante sensaciones desagradables y agradables. & hojas blancas, lápices y colores, información de emociones.\\
          & Autoconcepto & \emph{Dibujo de sí mismo y para los otros} & reafirmar el conocimiento de uno mismo a través de la relación que establecemos con los otros.& hojas y colores.\\
          & \emph{Retroalimentación} & devolución de comentarios respecto a las actividades & \\
    \midrule
    Día 3 & Inicio de sesión & \emph{Recapitulación} & retomar algunas reflexiones de las sesiones anteriores& Diapositivas\\
          & Respiración y cuento & \emph{lectura} & Autoestima, confianza en uno mismo y las relaciones interpersonales. & Extracto del cuento, e.j. el principito.\\
          & Autoestima y relaciones interpersonales & \emph{Percepción social y formas de vida} & Reflexionar sobre la forma de vida actual y su relación con el estrés. Identificar el tipo de situaciones estresantes ante las que se encuentran en este momento de la vida. Dar a conocer los tipos de estresores y comportamientos  al afrontarlos. & Anexo de tipos de comportamiento y estrés.\\
          & Collage & elaborar un collage en el que se represente la forma en la que es percibida la sociedad que nos rodea, valores actuales, creencias, estereotipos, etc. & papel bond, plumones, pegamento, tijeras,revistas, crayones. Preguntas de reflexión\\
          & Retroalimentación y cierre & los collage elaborados por grupos se exponen y retroalimentan & collages.\\
    \midrule
    Día 4 & comunicación asertiva & \emph{Teléfono descompuesto} & Que cada participante identifique las características y técnicas en la comunicación asertiva & Diapositivas, plumones.\\
          & Solución de conflictos y trabajo colaborativo & \emph{el nudo humano} & reafirmar la importancia del trabajo colaborativo a través de la comunicación no-verbal & dinámica grupal.\\
          & Respiración y reflexión \emph{Tensión y relajación} & Distensión e incorporación del grupo a la introspección y reflexión de sus objetivos y proyecto de vida & Música e instrucciones de la actividad.\\
          & Proyecto de vida & \emph{Proyecto de vida} & reflexionar sobre el proyecto de vida, logros, oportunidades, objetivos, a través de una redacción y compartir algunos escritos al grupo & dibujo del árbol para proyecto de vida.\\
          & cierre del taller &  retroalimentación y despedida & comentarios y reflexiones finales.\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Instead of use `small` I used a column a little more wider, but as you could see is very narrow.

Thanks.

Comment: There is space between the columns, so the total width will be more than `\linewidth`...